# Unable to get default value in XML attribute after XSD transformation

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xsd, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Database Version 19c (19.0.0.0.0)
I have created an XSD schema and have an XML and assume to add default value in XML after using transform. and tried in 2 ways but not getting my result as expected.

Way I:

```
declare  
    l_xsd   xmltype;  
    l_xml   xmltype;  
    l_xmltrans xmltype;  
begin  
    l_xsd := xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  <xs:element name="Department">  
    <xs:complexType>  
      <xs:sequence>  
        <xs:element name="Employees">  
          <xs:complexType>  
            <xs:sequence>  
              <xs:element name="Employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">  
                <xs:complexType>  
                  <xs:simpleContent>  
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">  
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Emp_no" use="optional"/>  
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Emp_Name" use="optional"/>  
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="Salary" use="optional" default="0"/>  
                    </xs:extension>  
                  </xs:simpleContent>  
                </xs:complexType>  
              </xs:element>  
            </xs:sequence>  
          </xs:complexType>  
        </xs:element>  
      </xs:sequence>  
      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="dept_no"/>  
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dept_name"/>  
    </xs:complexType>  
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>');  
      
    l_xml := xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Department dept_no="10" dept_name="Sales">  
    <Employees>  
        <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Kumar" Salary="1000" />  
        <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Sudhir" />  
    </Employees>  
</Department>');  
--      
    SELECT XMLTRANSFORM (l_xsd, l_xml) INTO l_xmltrans FROM DUAL;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_xmltrans.getclobval ());
end;
```

Way II:

```
BEGIN   
  DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.deleteschema(  
    schemaurl     => 'kumar_schema.xsd',  
    delete_option => DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.delete_cascade_force);   
END;   
/  
  
  
DECLARE  
    l_schema   CLOB;  
BEGIN  
    l_schema := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  <xs:element name="Department">  
    <xs:complexType>  
      <xs:sequence>  
        <xs:element name="Employees">  
          <xs:complexType>  
            <xs:sequence>  
              <xs:element name="Employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">  
                <xs:complexType>  
                  <xs:simpleContent>  
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">  
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Emp_no" use="optional"/>  
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Emp_Name" use="optional"/>  
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="Salary" use="optional" default="0"/>  
                    </xs:extension>  
                  </xs:simpleContent>  
                </xs:complexType>  
              </xs:element>  
            </xs:sequence>  
          </xs:complexType>  
        </xs:element>  
      </xs:sequence>  
      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="dept_no"/>  
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dept_name"/>  
    </xs:complexType>  
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>';  
  
  
    DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerschema (  
        schemaurl         => 'kumar_schema.xsd',  
        schemadoc         => l_schema,  
        local             => TRUE,  
        gentypes          => FALSE,  
        gentables         => FALSE,  
        enablehierarchy   => DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.enable_hierarchy_none);  
END;  
/  
  
  
  
  
  
DECLARE  
  l_xml      CLOB;  
  l_xmltype  XMLTYPE;  
BEGIN  
  l_xml := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Department dept_no="10" dept_name="Sales">  
    <Employees>  
        <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Kumar" Salary="1000" />  
        <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Sudhir" />  
    </Employees>  
</Department>';  

  l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(l_xml, 'kumar_schema.xsd');
  l_xmltype.schemavalidate;    

  dbms_output.put_line (l_xmltype .getclobval());
END;  
/
```

in both the way I get below result:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Department dept_no="10" dept_name="Sales">
      <Employees>
         <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Kumar" Salary="1000"/>
         <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Sudhir"/>
       </Employees>
    </Department>
```

But I assume this result:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Department dept_no="10" dept_name="Sales">
      <Employees>
         <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Kumar" Salary="1000"/>
         <Employee Emp_no="101" Emp_Name="Sudhir" Salary="0"/>
       </Employees>
    </Department>
```

because I have used ***<xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="Salary" use="optional" default="0"/>*** in XSD

Need your advice.

Comment: For the first attempt, As per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions229.htm XMLTRANSFORM is expecting an XSL style sheet not a XSD. Now you could use XSL to add the attribute if it dosn't exist but using a XSD will not work

Comment: Thanks @ShaunPeterson, I will try this. What about my 2nd option? Can you guide here also.

Comment: Not as familiar with the second option.... but my thoughts would be, you are creating a XML type and assigning a XSD --> the xml complies with the XSD as Salary is optional so no change or error expected --> you then validate it against the XSD again it complies so no change or error expected. So the way it is working makes logical sense to me.  If your original XML had the Salary attribute with no value, then maybe this would default to 0 but do not see how having a default value (especially for a optional attribute) would create the attribute.